Jetpack Compose - Reduce Material3 TopAppBar Height
I am migrating my code from Material2 to Material3. The TopAppBar in Material3 has a larger height than Material2, which is not what I want. I have tried reducing the height using the following without success:

Setting the window insets to zero does nothing: windowInsets = WindowInsets(top = 0.dp, bottom = 0.dp)
Setting the modifier height just made the text inside the bar align to the top of the screen: modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp)

I cannot duplicate and modify the source code because there are too many internal functions and classes for it to be feasible.

If you want your app to use Material3, a larger app bar is part of Material3 and what users would expect.

Most user's don't know what Material3 is and whether an app is using it or not. Being able to modify more aspects of it seems like a reasonable request considering I also can't easily modify the height in Material2.

This will reduce the height to the original material design height and the text inside the bar will remain vertically centered:
TopAppBar(
    // required parameters,
    modifier = Modifier.heightIn(max = 56.dp),
)

